# Javascript isNaN not working

Tags: javascript

for some reason it's not validating the isNan code, can you guys help me? But it's validating the not null condition, but is not appearing any pop up when i insert letters

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function resultado()
{

  if(massa.peso.value=="") || (isNaN(massa.peso.value)==false))
   alert("Preencha a peso");

   if(massa.altura.value=="") || (isNaN(massa.altura.value)==false)) 
    alert("Preencha a altura");



}

</script>
</head>
```

html:

```
<body>
<h1>INDICE MASSA CORPORAL</h1>
<form name="massa">
  Peso: <input type="text" name="peso">
  Altura: <input type="text" name="altura">
  <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" onclick="resultado()">
  <input type="reset" value="Limpar">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You might want to count your brackets.

Comment: your IFs are both missing one (

Comment: Hi, i put them now and its not working anyway

Comment: `isNaN(massa.peso.value)` is supposed to return boolean, no need to add `== false` and parenthesis, which lead you to mistake

Comment: It looks like you wanted `if(massa.peso.value=="" || !isNaN(massa.peso.value))`, but that is the same as `if(!isNaN(massa.peso.value))`, because if it is `NaN`, then it is not `""`.

Comment: I think you revert the condition... you want to raise the alert if its not a number and not if its not not a number, just : isNaN(massa.peso.value). And replace input type="submit" by input="button" to prevent form submit.

Comment: Remove <form></form> as it is reloading the page.

Comment: you shoudl edit your question fixing the brackets first

Comment: `if (!massa.altura.value)` check if is null, NaN, spaces, undefined..

Answer (score 0):

I see that, you are checking isNaN with false rather than true.
isNaN will return true if the parameter is not a number and false if it is a number.

I think it's perfectly working fine(ofcourse with the brackets on). Please find the plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/rbu7sFhJoKJuFgFqDoFY

```
function resultado()
{
 if((massa.peso.value=="") || (isNaN(massa.peso.value)==true))
  console.log("Preencha a peso");

 if((massa.altura.value=="") || (isNaN(massa.altura.value)==true)) 
  console.log("Preencha a altura");
}

<body>
  <h1>INDICE MASSA CORPORAL</h1>
  <form name="massa">
    Peso: <input type="text" name="peso" />
    Altura: <input type="text" name="altura" />
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm" onclick="resultado()" />
    <input type="reset" value="Limpar" />
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To echo to the another answer  that you messed up your condition  it should be

```
(massa.peso.value=="") || (isNaN(massa.peso.value)==true)
```

To add , Also you are using submit event ,not sure what you exactly you want here but if its just front end validaion , you might want to change the button to a regular button or change the default action of onsubmit event

https://jsfiddle.net/hv1nr063/

Answer (score 0):

```js
function resultado(){
   let peso = document.getElementsByName("peso")[0]
     , altura = document.getElementsByName("altura")[0];
  
   if( !peso.value ){
     alert("Preencha a peso");
     return;
   }
   
   if( !altura.value ){
     alert("Preencha a altura");
     return;
   }
}
```

```html
<h1>INDICE MASSA CORPORAL</h1>
<form name="massa">
  Peso: <input type="text" name="peso" />
  Altura: <input type="text" name="altura" />
  <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" onclick="resultado()">
  <input type="reset" value="Limpar">
</form>
```